# Both with verbs

Tags: verbs, word-order, parallelism

I have a doubt about the use of "both" with verbs. 
Is it correct to write "I am writing both in English and in Italian to you" or "I am writing to you in English and in Italian both"? Thank you for taking your time for answering me.

Comment: Personally, I find the most natural word order to be:

"I am writing to you in both English and Italian."

Comment: I would use "I am writing *both* in English and in Italian to you". Putting "both" first tells you that two nouns will follow. If you put "both" at the end, then by the time you get to it you have to backtrack to understand what nouns "both" includes.

Answer (score 1):

With the positioning of the word **both**, if both refers to the subject of a clause, we can use it in the normal mid position for adverbs, between the subject and main verb, after a modal verb or the first auxiliary verb, or after be as a main verb.

**Both...and** is a linking expression as it emphasises the link between 2 things making a stronger connection than using just **and** alone

So therefore, the correct position of the word **both** in the sentences you gave in your question is

> I am writing both in English and in Italian to you